# PhoneGap :Retrieve the next data from table By increment sessionStorage

Tags: jquery, cordova, session-storage, sessionstorage

I have a ID (1) of a record in the database and each time when I click the "NEXT" button, I wish to increment the ID into 2 and retrieve the next data. I store the ID into the sessionStorage.ID and later when I retrieve it and

```
sessionStorage.ID =sessionStorage.ID +1
```

The sessionStorage should be equal to 2 but it display as "11". How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sessionStorage.ID = parseInt(sessionStorage.ID) + 1;
```

When you store the ID in sessionStorage, it gets saved as a string, so the `+` sign concatenates the number instead of adding it.